# Radio Buttons not showing checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, radio-button

I have created some radio buttons that when clicked show a price. The code I am using is below..

```
   <label for='<?php echo $price; ?>' class="tabs">
   <input type="radio" name="j" class="radioBtn" id='<?php echo $price; ?>' value="<?php echo $price; ?>" onclick="calculate(this);" />
   <?php echo $number; ?>
   </label>
```

The price is then being shown like this:

```
<span class="prices" id="output"></span>
```

by

```
function calculate(obj) { document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = obj.value;}
```

The prices and buttons are working correctly, but I need to style the label to show that the correct button has being selected. In the DOM it says that the radio input is checked, but it's not being rendered in the HTML.

I also need to get the first checkbox to be selected as default.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction at all please?

Paddy

Comment: Depending on what version of HTML you are using, the id attribute of your input boxes may be invalid.  For instance, HTML4 requires the id to begin with a letter.  So price wouldn't be the best choice of a unique identifier especially if you had 2 identical prices.

Comment: All prices are different at the moment. Would this be a reason why the radio input isn't showing as checked?

Comment: I created a static version of this code (without the PHP variables) and it worked ok.  Would it be possible to see the entire rendered HTML?

Comment: Absolutely, gist can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86578b3dc89e8593060133733cfc2dcf

Comment: and if it helps, the page is question is: http://www.grofar.com/pricing-2/

Answer (score 2):

The grofar.com site looks fine to me.  When you say the styling isn't working on the label, what exactly do you mean?  Are you trying to apply a different color, font, etc.?

As for making the first option selected by default, you have a few options.  The first would be to use PHP to determine the first one and add the `checked` attribute to the `input` element. For instance, if you are doing a loop, use an if/then statement to set the checked attribute if the loop counter is 1.

A second option is to use jQuery to select the first box:

```
$(function() {
   $("input[name='j']:first").prop("checked", true);
});
```

However, with that method, your `calculate` function is not called and therefore the price is not updated.

A third option is to use jQuery to simulate a click of the first box:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name='j']:first").click();
});
```

That will select the box and update the price.

Comment: I am trying to the the checked radio label to be a different colour and remove the input itself. However without the checked input I can't use jQuery to add a class to the parent

Comment: Instead of removing the input, can you just hide it (```onclick="calculate(this); $(this).hide()"```) or disable it (```onclick="calculate(this); $(this).prop('disabled', true)"```)?  Then you could still apply the new style to the parent.